# FFMpeg quality degradation when using NVENC

Tags: ffmpeg, nvenc

I'm using ffmpeg to encode a folder full of static PNG images into video format. Among other things, I set the quality to 20Mbps and preset to `veryslow`. Everything works. However, as soon as I switch from the default H264 encoder to NVENC, it seems the quality settings are completely ignored, and I get default (terrible) quality.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Share your full command.

Answer (score 2):

libx264 and h.264 nvenc don't share all their options. Run the following 2 help commands to list their options:

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc
ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264
```

On mine (v5.0 in win10) `h264_nvenc` does not support `-preset veryslow` option.